# Recording Skype conference calls on OSX?

Tags: macos, skype, open-source, audio-recording

I am looking for an open-source way to generate an audio record of Skype conference calls under OSX 10.5 or higher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Soundflower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) to pass audio from the Skype call to Garageband.  Fairly easy and all free/open source

Comment: Thanks - this sounds doable. Will definitely try it and report back here.

Comment: Found http://www.informationmarketingcentral.com/content/how-record-skype-calls-free a page that explains the details. Worked fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel, there was never a need (or an option) for using `a href` anywhere in SEN. Just to make your link more friendly (and should also be clickable), I'll repeat it here: http://www.informationmarketingcentral.com/content/how-record-skype-calls-free and nowadays we even have a *help "button"* telling us how we can get a similar result than using href: `[page](URL)` = [page](http://www.informationmarketingcentral.com/content/how-record-skype-calls-free)

Comment: Except the link above wasn't clickable due to a weird restriction on comments: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2622/url-href-in-comments-didnt-work-this-once/2623#2623

Answer (score 1):

Rogue Amoeba (creators of LineIn) makes other audio utilities such as [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/). This would also solve this problem.

Comment: Sounds really nice, but it ain't open source and the limitation seems to be it will record audio in good quality only for the first 10 minutes.

Comment: @Cawas Since the user accepted an answer that required the commercial, closed source GarageBand, I didn't see an issue with that.

Comment: Personally, I don't see any issue with a good solution... But GarageBand comes by default on mac. At least on mine it did. Probably by opensource he meant free, but maybe he meant he wanted to actually see some code. Anyways... Lovely solutions. :P

Answer (score 0):

There's also [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com) plugin for Skype:

- records Skype calls automatically saves them to your mailbox and/or
  to disk
- saves chat history along with call recordings in view of
  conversations

*Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of G-Recorder*